# Sending audio output from OBS to microphone on linux

Tags: linux, microphone, obs

I am currently using OBS in my home office setup in order to be able to add cool effects and backgrounds to my video calls and meetings. I am using obs-v4l2sink (https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink) in order to stream to a virtual webcam, but I have had no such luck when it comes to streaming audio to a virtual microphone.

Is there a way to output the audio captured by OBS to a virtual microphone?

Comment: Good question, but completely off-topic here, as this is a programming Q&A site, and this is not a programming question.

Comment: @Flimzy Which stackexchange should I ask the question on then? https://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: Probably. Possibly Unix&Linux, or even AskUbuntu (if you're using Ubuntu, of course)

Comment: I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421014/share-an-audio-playback-stream-through-a-live-audio-video-conversation-like-sk) which worked for my situation, for example. I'm not sure if it's close enough to your question to be helpful or not.